# Operation at strings and arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string, mysqli

I wish to ask about operations over arrays in php. 

I'm capturing two cells from one table in database, which are holding strings formatted like "1;3;6;" and whole second table - it has numbers in first column and names in second. Im dividing strings from first table into two arrays using     `explode()` function, and second table into next two arrays with column per array. Therefore, when     `print_r()` is used over those three arrays, I will see:

 error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

> **first table**
>       
>   "amount" *string transformed into array called*     `$ship_storage_parted_amount` Array
>       (
>           [0] => 5
>           [1] => 10
>           [2] => 
>       )
>
> "ware id" *string transformed into array called*     `$ship_cargo_bay_parted` Array
>       (
>           [0] => 1
>           [1] => 2
>           [2] => 
>       )
>
> **second table transfomed into two arrays     `$ware_id` and     `$ware_name`**
>   
> *table contains 7 rows at all*
>   
> Array
>   (
>       [0] => Array
>           (
>               [ware_id] => 1
>               [name] => Energized energy cell
>           )
>
> [1] => Array
>           (
>               [ware_id] => 2
>               [name] => Depleted energy cell
>           )
>
> [2] => Array
>           (
>               [ware_id] => 3
>               [name] => Vegetables
>           )
>
> [3] => Array
>           (
>               [ware_id] => 4
>               [name] => Meat
>           )
>   )

I want to achieve next thing: showing at website appropriate equal names from second table according to their IDs with conjunction of what is stored in first table.

Therefore, it should look like:

> Energized energy cell x5
>   Depleted energy cell  x10

When I've tryied to show them like that: 

 
`echo $ware_name[$ship_cargo_bay-1]." x".$ship_storage_parted_amount[$ware_position];`

 it resulted in such output:

> Energized energy cell x

where     `$ship_cargo_bay` contains all captured string "ware id" and     `$ware_position` was amount counter. Amount counter pointed at 3rd array element which is empty; but when I reorganized printing with     for()

`for($i=0;$i}lowerthan{$ware_counter;$i++)
{echo $ware_name[$ship_cargo_bay_parted[$i]]." x".$ship_storage_parted_amount[$i];}`

I've got now

> x5 x10 x x

And my poor knowledge ends here. As I know, first attempt of printing shall not work at all, but why I've got such output in second attempt is over my understanding.

Comment: Add this at the beginning of your code: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Added, now looks nearly as intended - great thanks. However I'm unable to hide that - <p style> or <font> wont play.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found reasons, where I made mistakes. After carefully checking names of each single variable, printing what exactly everything contains, I found that Ive somehow mispelled variable names.

```
for($i=1;$i<$ware_counter;$i++)
            {
            echo $ware_name[$ship_storage_parted[$i]]." x ".$ship_storage_parted_amount[$i]."<br/>";
            }
```

This few lines gives exactly what Ive needed. Therefore Im putting it here - maybe someone will encounter similar problem.